# How to control timezones in upgraded system

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, ntp

During the upgrade from 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04

I noticed `ntp` is no longer supported, but not removed.

Does this mean there is now a systemd process running alongside `ntp` and possibly double work is being done on the upgraded system?

How do I check that only `ntp` is running?

Comment: I guess ntp is now replaced with `timedatectl`?  Take a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-20-04), for example.

Comment: NTP is not removed to retain any kind of old custom config a user might have had. But the NTP clients (and servers) are all providing time-daemon and conflicting with time-daemon (have a look at `apt-cache search time-daemo`). So only one of them will ever be really installed and active.  If you want to switch from the old ntp, if you only need a simple ntp client systemd-timesyncd will do and if you need more chrony is the way to go.